# Python, Regex: Cannot get coefficients from the equation(s)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to get coefficients from this equation using regex and later multiple equations:

`2a+3b=c`

However I get this annoying error. I checked my code and everything looks fine for me. This is the error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Here is my code:

```
import re

all_coefficients = []

def equation_solver(*equations):
    for equation in equations:
        sides = equation.split('=')
        coefficients = []
        for side in sides:
            terms = re.split(r"\+", side)
            for term in terms:
                coefficient = re.match(r"\d", term)
                if coefficient == None:
                    coefficient = 1
                coefficients.append(int(coefficient.group(0)))
        all_coefficients.append(coefficients)


equations = []

while True:
    equations.append(input())
    if input() == 's':
        break

equation_solver(*equations)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are overwriting `coefficient = 1` and then call `coefficient.group(0)`

Comment: oh I see. Thank you for pointing that out. How can I be really stupid??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s causing the error because `re.match` did not find any coefficient in the term `c` so if it didn’t find any coefficient (read carefully) you assigned the coefficient value as `1` BUT you cannot use `group` now because coefficient is an integer now!! So you use `group` function before you convert it to an integer, and it will look something like this:

```
import re

all_coefficients = []

def equation_solver(*equations):
    for equation in equations:
        sides = equation.split('=')
        coefficients = []
        for side in sides:
            terms = re.split(r"\+", side)
            for term in terms:
                coefficient = re.match(r"\d", term)
                if coefficient == None:
                    coefficient = 1
                else:
                    coefficient = coefficient.group(0) # Use group beforehand
                coefficients.append(int(coefficient))
        all_coefficients.append(coefficients)


equations = []

while True:
    equations.append(input())
    if input() == 's':
        break

equation_solver(*equations)
```

Hope this helps